# "Within the past year" vs. "In the past year"

Tags: word-choice, differences, prepositions, time

I'm having an argument with a co-worker about phrasing.  We have a document that makes reference to someone having experience working "in the past year", and later it states "must have experience working within the past year."

I say there is no difference, he says there is.

Comment: What difference does he find?

Comment: Your boss just peeked around the corner and told me to tell you to stop arguing and get back to work, both of you.

Answer (score 3):

I have to disagree with the other comments here. In the example, "in" would be erroneous and it should be either "within" or "during".

"Must have experience working **within** the past year." = Had a job of *any duration* (i.e., temporary or long-term) *at some time* over the last 365 days.

"Must have experience working **during** the past year." = Had a job *throughout the entire* 365-day period.

"In" with "year" would apply to a short action or event in a specific year: "He began working **in** 1978" or "... **in** the last year of the 19th Century".

Answer (score 1):

"Someone having experience working 'in the past year'" sounds to my ear that the person should have been employed for the entire year, while "must have experience working within the past year" suggests that the person might have worked for just one day during the previous year. Both examples sound like "HR-Speak" and need to be more specific if you want to attract qualified applicants for the position.

Answer (score 0):

In your example there is no effective difference.  In general, though:

"Working **within** the past year" applies best to work that began and ended during the past year.

"Working **in** the past year" more gracefully applies to work that began more than a year ago or is ongoing.

"Working **during** the past year" would emphasize that the work may have been brief or sporadic.

"Working **over** the past year" would require the work to have spanned the entire year.

Answer (score -1):

Some one working for the past year means he is no longer working,he worked previous year.within the past year means he was working on that same year

Comment: That is not what it means.